# regular expression for finding the parenthesis using python

Tags: python, parentheses

i m trying to find the parenthesis before or within or after a text from a txt file, I tried it through regular expression, it gave correct result against {} and [] but not for ()
code is

```
 import re;
    file="C:/Python26/test.txt";
    f=open("paranthesis.txt",'w');
    pattern ='[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]|\(|\)|\]|\[|\}|\{';
    with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();
    ##    c=0;
        for word in lines:
            if re.match(pattern, word):
                f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n");
    ##            f.write('1'"\n");
    ##            c=c+1;
            else:
                f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n");
    ##            f.write('0'"\n");
    ##            c=c+1;
    ##    print c;
        f.close();
```

this code generates '1' against every [] and {} in the text but did not give result against ()

Comment: `\(|\)` this should match `()`. Do you want to match anything between them as well? If you want to match `()` exactly, you should use `\(\)` without `|`.

Comment: My regular expression gave result as:                 123[worker] 1
[IL-2] 1
{shaheen123} 1
wo(rker) 0
(123.321) 1
{ 1
[ 1
} 1
] 1
( 1
) 1
a[s{d(dsa)}] 1
an 0
sde 0
all 0
about 0
above 0
shhII 0
IV 0
IL-IV 0
+ 0                                                                           but after changing \(|\) with \(\) result is changed but not got the desired result                                     123[worker] 1
[IL-2] 1
{shaheen123} 1
wo(rker) 0
(123.321) 0
{ 1
[ 1
} 1
] 1
( 0
) 0
a[s{d(dsa)}] 1
an 0
sde 0
all 0
about 0
above 0
shhII 0
IV 0
IL-IV 0
+ 0
me+you 0

Comment: Your code *matches* `(` and `)` in the text you posted.

Comment: I want a regular expression which identify all three types of parenthesis depending upon their presence at any position in a token / string

Comment: first you need to use regex format for your pattern , (you omit `r`) , then what you mean exactly by *did not give result against ()* ? did you mean 2 couple parenthesis ? or what ?

Comment: Your code is indented strangely and Python statements generally don't need a `;` at the end. It would also be helpful is you supplied some example input, results, and desired results.

Comment: If you need to detect nested parenthesis, you cannot use regular expressions; they don't support recursion.

Comment: Input result is every token with 1 or 0 which denotes the parenthesis existence in each line, 1 for true and 0 for false                                                                   123[worker] 1
[IL-2] 1
{shaheen123} 1
wo(rker) 0
(123.321) 1
{ 1
[ 1
} 1
] 1
( 0
) 0
a[s{d(dsa)}] 1
an 0
sde 0
all 0
about 0
above 0
shhII 0
IV 0
IL-IV 0
+ 0
me+you 0

Comment: nd my desired result is                                  123[worker] 1
[IL-2] 1
{shaheen123} 1
wo(rker) 1
(123.321) 1
{ 1
[ 1
} 1
] 1
( 0
) 0
a[s{d(dsa)}] 1
an 0
sde 0
all 0
about 0
above 0
shhII 0
IV 0
IL-IV 0
+ 0
me+you 0
where wo(rker) gave result '0'. it should gave the result 1

Comment: I don't need to detect the nested parenthesis, i need only once but i need whether the type of parenthesis, regular expression detect it.

Comment: @ShaheenGul if you want to get a proper answer you must add all of your  describes in comment to your answer with your desire out put and input !

Comment: also you may note that `re.match` match the string from leading , if you want to match whole of your string you need to use `re.search()`, if you edit your question and express your request clearly , may i could help , you , also keep in mind that (for sounds like your codes) the users you're ask them to answer you could not understand whole of your code till you explain the logic behind your code !